# More than one contentDescription for a button

Tags: android, button, dialog, onclick

In my `activity` I have a method that reads the `contentDescriptio`n of a button and get the phone number and calls it.

I have  a list of all departments in the company. But if for the same department we have more than one number what should I do. How to add more than one `contentDescription` for a button to pop a dialog that allows the user to choose between which number should he call.

```
public class ContactUs extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);

    ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ContactUs.this , Introduction.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_out);

        }
    });
}

public void onClickCall(View view) {

    final String phoneNumber = view.getContentDescription().toString().trim();

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel://" + phoneNumber));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Test Alert").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

}

public void onClickMail(View view) {


    String mailaddress = view.getContentDescription().toString().trim();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { mailaddress});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));

}
}
```

Comment: Can't you just save the multiple numbers in a comma separated string, split them when you retrieve the value and show a popup list for the user to click one?

Comment: can you please help with the code

Answer (score 0):

When your are setting content description to button append them with commas separated.

after appending all the phone numbers your content description will be like `//phoneNumber1,phoneNumber2,phoneNumber3`

now read  content description from  your view

```
final String allPhoneNumbers = view.getContentDescription().toString().trim();

//say phoneNumber1,phoneNumber2,phoneNumber3

String[] arrPhoneNumbers = allPhoneNumbers .split(",");
```

now you have all phone numbers in this array.